# PURE JS get selected option data attribute value returns Null

Tags: javascript

I have this html:

```
<select onchange="check_status(this);" name="status[171]">    
    <option selected="true" value="open" data="04f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605">open</option>    
    <option value="in_process" data="04f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605">pending</option>    
    <option value="finished" data="04f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605">finished</option>    
    <option value="canceled" data="04f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605">canceled</option>    
</select>
```

and js

```
function check_status(obj){    
    var uid = obj.getAttribute('data');
    alert(uid);
}
```

but it always alerts null instead of data value
Where is the problem guys? Thanks

Comment: Btw, the `data` attribute doesn't exist. If you want to use custom data, use something like `data-uid` instead.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem is that you get select element and not selected option element as function argument. And it does not have the `data` attribute. You have to get the option attribute like so:

```js
function check_status(obj) {
  var uid = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-uid');
  alert(uid);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="check_status(this);" name="status[171]">

  <option selected="true" value="open" data-uid="01f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a601">open</option>
  <option value="in_process" data-uid="02f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a602">pending</option>
  <option value="finished" data-uid="03f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a603">finished</option>
  <option value="canceled" data-uid="04f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a604">canceled</option>
</select>
```

Notice that I changed the attribute name to `data-uid` for it to be valid according to HTML5 specificaion.

Comment: `data` is an **invalid** HTML5 attribute. You should use `data-*` like `data-uid` and respectively: `.getAttribute("data-uid")`

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to get select data attribute, and not option's.

Also, I can see that all you `data` attributes are identical. Then you can move it from option to select itself: `<select onchange="check_status(this);" name="status[171]" data="04f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605" >` and use code snipped from your question unmodified.

```js
function check_status(obj) {
  var uid =  obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data');
  alert(uid)
}
```

```html
<select onchange="check_status(this);" name="status[171]">
  <option selected="true" value="open" data="open04f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605">open</option>
  <option value="in_process" data="pending104f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605">pending</option>
  <option value="finished" data="finished04f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605">finished</option>
  <option value="canceled" data="canceled04f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605">canceled</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

You define custom attributes using the "data" attribute. In your code, there is not custome attribute which I'm sure you wanted it to be an ID. The exact format is `"data-*"`, where `"*"` is replaced with the desired custom attribute name, then set to the desired string value. So in your code, it should ideally be:

```
<select onchange="check_status(this);" name="status[171]">
  <option selected="true" value="open" data-id="open04f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605">open</option>
  <option value="in_process" data-id="pending104f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605">pending</option>
  <option value="finished"   data-id="finished04f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605">finished</option>
  <option value="canceled"   data-id="canceled04f2cf35e4d7a1c0158459fd0450a605">canceled</option>
</select>
```

assuming you want the custom attribute to be "id".

There are two ways you can retrieve the value of "data" attributes using pure JavaScript: in addition to the good old fashion get/setAttribute(), you can also access using the "dataset" property of the element

Using DOM's getAttribute() property

```
function check_status(obj) {
      var myoption = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex];
      var uid = myoption.getAttribute('data');
      alert(uid);
      // setting and removing the data-id attribute
      myoption.setAttribute("data-id", "foo") //changes "data-id" to "foo"
      myoption.removeAttribute("data-id") //removes "data-id" attribute entirely
 }
```

Using JavaScript's dataset property

```
function check_status(obj) {
      var myoption = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex];
      var uid = myoption.dataset.id;
      alert(uid);
      var statusId = myoption.dataset["id"] 
      alert(statusId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function check_status(obj){    
    var uid = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data');
    alert(uid);
}
```